# Why does my for loop throw an "out_of_range" error?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and for a test problem I am using a for loop with condition `prices.size()-1` so the vector does not go out of range.

```
std::vector<int> prices {7,1,5,3,6,4};

int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {
    int total {0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < prices.size()-1; i++) {
        if (prices.at(i+1) > prices.at(i)) {
            total += prices.at(i+1) - prices.at(i);
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

But it is throwing this this runtime error that I cannot decipher:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

I cannot figure out the problem, can someone please show me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `size_t` is an **unsigned** type. Think what will happen in `size()-1` when `size()` is 0 (as the error message clearly says it is).

Comment: @engf-010 sorry I wasn't born with this knowledge :P

Comment: @engf-010 this isn't directed at the OP, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the error message carefully:

> this->size() (which is 0)

The error message indicates that the passed-in vector is empty. Its `size()` is 0. Now take a closer look at the `for`-loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < prices.size()-1; i++)
```

We've established that `prices.size()` is 0, so this becomes, effectively:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < -1; i++)
```

But `i` is a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type, so -1 gets casted to an unsigned type.

Now, perform a little experiment yourself, see what output you get from the following statement:

```
std::cout << (size_t)-1 << std::endl;
```

Because of this, even though the vector is empty, the `for` loop's condition will still evaluate to `true`, and inside the for loop the code will attempt to access a non-existent array value, hence the exception.

Note that the function's parameter of `prices` has nothing to do with the global `prices` vector. The code from your program that you did not show passes in an empty vector, resulting in this error. Why the vector that gets passed in is empty, this is something you will need to figure out on your own.

Note that it's fairly easy to tweak the `for`-loop, just slightly, so that this edge case gets correctly handled. Simply change the `for` loop's condition as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i+1 < prices.size(); i++)
```

Even though this seems to be the same thing, it's not (at least until you manage to create an array with about four billion, or so, values -- more on a 64 bit platform). Welcome to C++.

Comment: Great answer! And I just realized the testing platform delivers different vectors to test the solution, which is why one of them was size 0. So that makes more sense now.

Comment: Small correction: the 1 gets promoted to an unsigned type during the subtraction, so you end up with `(size_t)0 - (size_t)1` which results in a large number. The conversion happens during the subtraction, not during the comparison.